# How to merge every three (or more) elements of list in one in python?

Tags: python, list, join, merge

```
list = [1, 'one', 'first', 2, 'two', 'second', 3, 'three', 'third', 4, 'four', 'fourth', 5, 'five', 'fifth', 6, 'six', 'sixth']
```

is it compact way to make new list like this? (merging 3 elements, then another 3...):

```
['1onefirst', '2twosecond', '3threethird', '4fourfourth', '5fivefifth', '6sixsixth']
```

Comment: Sir, your right, i forget quotes. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with conversion to string and `join`:

```
N = 3
out = [''.join(map(str, lst[i:i+N])) for i in range(0, len(lst), N)]
```

Output:

```
['1onefirst',
 '2twosecond',
 '3threethird',
 '4fourfourth',
 '5fivefifth',
 '6sixsixth']
```

Comment: Understandable and elegant, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following solution is what you are looking for.

```
    list = [1, "one", "first", 2, "two", "second", 3, "three", "third",
    4, "four", "fourth", 5, "five", "fifth", 6, "six", "sixth"]

    def merge_list(list, n):
        temp_list = [list[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(list), n)]
        return [''. join(str(i) for i in temp_list) for temp_list in temp_list]

   list_merge_every_third = merge_list(list, 3)
   print(list_merge_every_third)
```

The resulting list looks like this:

['1onefirst', '2twosecond', '3threethird', '4fourfourth', '5fivefifth', '6sixsixth']

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a combination of list comprehensions and slices for this purpose in Python:

```py
# Defining the input list
input_list = [
    1, "one", "first",
    2, "two", "second",
    3, "three", "third",
    4, "four", "fourth",
    5, "five", "fifth",
    6, "six", "sixth"
]

# Using slices of the input in a list comprehension
list_merge_every_third = [
    ''.join(str(e) for e in input_list[i * 3 : i * 3 + 3])
    for i in range(len(input_list) // 3)
]
```

**Note:** You may first want to test if your input list length is a multiple of 3.

I also suggest not using the symbol "list" to designate your input, because it is a reserved keyword of the Python language to designate the list type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a generator to return the combined triplets like this:

```
input_list = [
    1, "one", "first",
    2, "two", "second",
    3, "three", "third",
    4, "four", "fourth",
    5, "five", "fifth",
    6, "six", "sixth"
]

def triples(_list):
    for i in range(0, len(_list), 3):
        yield ''.join(map(str, _list[i:i+3]))

print([triple for triple in triples(input_list)])
```

**Output:**

```
['1onefirst', '2twosecond', '3threethird', '4fourfourth', '5fivefifth', '6sixsixth']
```